# finding largest and smallest number in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to programming, please advise me if my code is correct.

I am trying to write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
        num = input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == 'done':
            break
        try:
            fnum = float(num)
        except:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
      lst = []
numbers = int(input('How many numbers: '))
for n in range(numbers):

    lst.append(num)
print("Maximum element in the list is :", max(lst), "\nMinimum element in the list is :", min(lst))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct, there are just a couple things you need to change:

```
lst = []
while True:
    user_input = input('Enter a number: ')
    if user_input == 'done':
        break
    try:
        lst.append(int(user_input))
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input')

if lst:
    print('max: %d\nmin: %d' % (max(lst), min(lst)))
```

Also, since you said you're new to programming, I'll explain what I did, and why.

---

First, there's no need to set `largest` and `smallest` to `None` at the beginning. I actually never even put those values in variables because we only need them to print them out.

All your code is then identical up to the `try/except block`. Here, I try to convert the user input into an integer and append it to the list all at once. If any of this fails, print `Invalid input`. My `except` section is a little different: it says `except ValueError`. This means "only run the following code if a `ValueError` occurs". It is always a good idea to be specific when catching errors because `except` by itself will catch **all** errors, including ones we don't expect and will want to see if something goes wrong.

We do not want to use a `continue` here because `continue` means "skip the rest of the code and continue to the next loop iteration". We don't want to skip anything here.

Now let's talk about this block of code:

```
numbers = int(input('How many numbers: '))
for n in range(numbers):
    lst.append(num)
```

From your explanation, there is no need to get more input from the user, so none of this code is needed. It is also always a good idea to put `int(input())` in a `try/except` block because if the user inputs something *other* than a number, `int(input())` will error out.

And lastly, the `print` statement:

```
print('max: %d\nmin: %d' % (max(lst), min(lst)))
```

In python, you can use the "string formatting operator", the percent (%) sign to put data into strings. You can use `%d` to fill in numbers, `%s` to fill in strings. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) is the full list of characters to put after the percent if you scroll down a bit. It also does a good job of explaining it, but here are some examples:

```
print('number %d' % 11)
```

```
x = 'world'
print('Hello, %s!' % x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_list = []

while True:
    user_input = int(input())

    if user_input < 0:
        break

    user_list.append(user_input)
  
print(min(user_list), max(user_list))
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.